# How to remove event listener in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to remove the `onRequest` listener added by `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener` after a request is made, like this:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request){
        chrome.extension.onRequest.removeListener();
        other_function(request);
    }
);
```

The problem is that I don't know if this works or not. I tried `chrome.extension.onRequest.hasListener`, which seems not to give the right answer, so I am wondering if there are some other ways to remove the `onRequest` listener or check if the listener exists or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`removeListener` takes an argument.  You need to name the listener function and then remove it by name:

```
function doStuff(request){
    chrome.extension.onRequest.removeListener(doStuff);
    other_function(request);
}
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(doStuff);
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function doStuff(request){
        chrome.extension.onRequest.removeListener(doStuff);
        other_function(request);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, apsillers, but doesn't the callback function (`doStuff` in this case) of the event listener need to be anonymous?

Comment: @chaohuang: no, there's no requirement for callbacks to be anonymous.

Comment: @Len So does this mean that this is different from the callbacks of `element.addEventListener` in DOM, as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) (below the first example, it says, quote, "If you want to pass parameters to the listener function, you have to use an anonymous function.")?

Comment: @chaohuang: They're using an anonymous function as contrasted to specifying the function name only—because they want to pass some argument to the function. If you wanted to use `removeEventListener` with that anonymous function, you'd have to pre-bind the function to a name, e.g. `var modifyTextFour = function() { modifyText("four"); };` (or `function modifyTextFour() { modifyText("four"); }`), then use that name with `addEventListener and `removeEventListener`. The function is still anonymous, per se, you've just bound it to a name afterwards.

Comment: @chaohuang: They say anonymous function, but what they really mean is that you can't pass an arbitrary argument to the callback, like `"four"` in that example's case—construct another function which does that part. If you want to remove the listener later, you'll need to have the same function you gave to `addEventListener`.

Comment: Indeed, that MDN description is a little bit vague.  Len's explanation is pretty good; I'll just add: if want to pass arbitrary arguments to a listener function that *aren't provided to the callback by the caller*, you need to wrap inside an anonymous function.

Comment: Dear @apsillers , I have an extension (as my background) which communicate with an external page (as my content script). How is possible to terminate listening in the content script side? I am using `port.onMessage.removeListener(this);` , however it is not worked!

Comment: @H.Aqjn `this` is almost never a function. When a function is called, `this` is the object that the function is called for, e.g., `foo.bar()` has a `this` of `foo`, not `bar`. --- The content script probably cannot remove listeners from the background; you must pass a message to your background telling it to remove a listener. If this answer does solve your problem, please post a new answer (and optionally link to this answer to show why it didn't solve your problem).

Comment: Dear @apsillers , my questions reach to limit and I could not ask more question. However, I do not want to remove listener of background from content script. Indeed, I want to remove the listener of content script in itself. I have a bidirectional communication between an external web page(or my content script) and a chrome extension (or my background).

Answer (score 11):

Another simple and straight forward approach when using anonymous functions:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, reply) {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(arguments.callee);
});
```

Comment: `arguments.callee` is not supported in strict mode as of EcmaScript 5 (2009)

Answer (score 0):

```
// define listener(s)
const createListener = (id, bookmark) => {
  // do something
};

React.useEffect(() => { 
  // Add listener(s)
  chrome.bookmarks.onCreated.addListener(createListener);

  // Return a function that removes listener(s)
  return () => {
    chrome.bookmarks.onCreated.removeListener(createListener);
  };
}, []);
```