# Stop event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I made a button which openning new page in new tab for example https://google.com. And I'm sending a message to the background script to start taking the URL of new opened page. The problem is that I don't know how to stop the listener after retrieving the URL. So it's continue the execution even after I closed that tab.

Popup.js

```
  $('#click').click(function(e)
        {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: 'https://google.com'});
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "googleisopened"}, function(response) {
            console.log(ok);
        });
  });
```

Background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting == "googleisopened")
    {
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        alert(changeInfo.url);
        }); 
    }
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove event listener in Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466567/how-to-remove-event-listener-in-chrome-extension)

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the url of the new tab once? or for as long as the new tab is opened?...

Comment: Yeah, I want to retrieve the URL once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me. I found a solution by myself.
Instead of using listener I started to use `tabs.getSelected` to retrieve page URL only when needed (not in cycle as in `onUpdated.addListener`).

So the **background** script will be next:

```
 chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting === "googleisopened")
    {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) 
        {
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(mylistener);
            function mylistener (tabId, changeInfo, tab)
            {
                alert(changeInfo.url);
                chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(mylistener);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're insterested in this function http://api.jquery.com/off/

It removes all of the events from the object so in your case you could just plug it anywhere in your click event like this:

```
 $(this).off('click');
 // Or like this if you want to be specific
 $('#click').off('click');
```

Comment: You can avoid removing all event handlers by using the [namespacing](http://api.jquery.com/off/#example-4) functionality of `.on()` and `.off()`... :D

Comment: I've tried to use it in the if statement but no effect

Comment: "plug it anywhere **in your click event**".

Background.js is in a different scope and should not be able to affect contents of your pop-up window.

Comment: But it doesn't solve the problem of stopping listener. I need to stop it in background after getting the URL. I have to use background script cause url opens in the new tab. The execution of the event in click is ending with sending message to the background script.

Comment: Off removes the trigger, but your function will continue working just fine. I think you're misunderstanding how 'off' works. It is not equal to a 'return', even if it was a first line of a function, your function will continue to work.