# Can I stop a function with the execution of a nested function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a chrome extension and have the following code:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((req, sender, sendRes) => {
        function cancel_error() {
            sendRes({error:true});
            return;
        };

        if (!req || !req.type)
            cancel_error();
        cancel_error();
        console.log("continued");
        sendRes({testRespone: true});
    });
```

In this snippet the listener still logs continued and sends the test response.
is there a way to stop the function like calling return with the execution of a nested function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove event listener in Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466567/how-to-remove-event-listener-in-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `return;` after you call the function:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((req, sender, sendRes) => {
  function cancel_error() {
    sendRes({error:true});
  };
  if (!req || !req.type) {
    cancel_error();
    return;
  }
  console.log("continued");
  sendRes({testRespone: true});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware that I can do that, I was just trying to unnecessary over-engineer something. So that I can just call cancel_error and not repeat always writing return.

Answer (score 0):

Adding return after you call the function will work

```
if (!req || !req.type) {
    cancel_error();
    return;
  }
```

or if you want to perform logic in your function, I would just return a value and then check what that value is, and respond accordingly.